# EntityManager Not Getting Injected in Jboss As 7

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, ejb-3.0, jndi

Its been two days i have been trying to inject Entitymanager in jboss AS 7,
    I have created datasource java:jboss/datasources/PinDS in jboss console connection is successful here is my

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0"> 

    <persistence-unit name="MyAppUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PinDS</jta-data-source>    
        <!-- com.testing.Action -->
        <class>com.testing.Action.GetENT</class>

         <!-- Hibernate properties -->
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"></property>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        </properties>        
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
  <display-name>LC</display-name>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

 <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/index.jsp</location>
</error-page>

 <description>MySQL Test App</description>
  <resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>java:jboss/datasources/PinDS</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

EJB class

```
package com.testing.Action;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class GetENT
 */
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class GetENT {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="MyAppUnit")
    private EntityManager em; //em is null tried @PersistenceUnit also
    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public GetENT() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void get(){
        try{
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyAppUnit"); //emf is gets created
        System.out.println(emf1);
        }catch(Exception w){
            w.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**NOTE:**

Using `EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyAppUnit");` I get emf,

however, using `@PersistenceContext(unitName="MyAppUnit")`, emf is null. Am I missing anything from my configuration?

Comment: What is your folder structure, is persistence.xml in classpath under META-INF.

Comment: @NayanWadekar my mistake was GetENT ge=new GetENT(); hence entitymanager is null....EJB should be injected...:')

Comment: You shouldn't instantiate GetENT by yourself, use injection or lookup; let container initialize it with all the dependencies.